# TypeError at /password_reset/ django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I try to override default password reset template and got this error:

```
TypeError at /password_reset/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is my urls

```
   url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView, {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're passing the view to your URL config is wrong.

Change:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView, ...)
```

to:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'), ...)
```

([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf))

Comment: url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset.html'), {'template_name': 'accounts/password_reset.html'}, name='password_reset'),